# How to install on Lenovo?

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on my new Lenovo 330s.

I thought this would be pretty easy as I have done it before but I am having a lot of trouble particularly at booting the BIOS.  I have an ISO image on a USB drive.  I have tried <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> and using Recovery > Restart now.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Press Enter at the short Lenovo Screen in the beginning.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks!  That is what I was looking for.  Very helpful.